# Error when passing matrix to static method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameter-passing

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')`

Hi, in this code block I get the error as mentioned above because of this line -> `result.data[j][i] = matrix.data[i][j].`

I try to call a static transpose method and pass it a matrix, that is already created. For some reason, it throws an error that the given matrix is **undefined** even though it isn't, or is it?

```
static transpose(matrix) {
    let result = new Matrix(this.cols, this.rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
        result.data[j][i] = matrix.data[i][j];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I'm following a neural network playlist by daniel Shiffman, and I got the error on this episode linked below.

https://youtu.be/r2-P1Fi1g60?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh

I've been stuck with this for so long, so thank you in advance.

Since I'm new to js, I thought passing values or references might not work the same as in Java. So I tried creating a test matrix inside the method but still, it threw the same problem that it is undefined.

```
static transpose(matrix) {
    let test = new Matrix(2,2);
    let result = new Matrix(this.cols, this.rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
        result.data[j][i] = test.data[i][j];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem myself!

The reason it was throwing an error, quite bad error actually so it was so hard to find. The reason was that, it is an static method, and in static methods you cannot access the matrix properties such as, this.rows or this.cols, since there is no data in them, thus throwing the error: Cannot set properties of undefined. It has to be a instance of a class for there to be data.

> let result = new Matrix(this.cols, this.rows);

Above mentioned line doesn't work in static methods since it's trying to access Matrix class properties and will cause the error later on.

Correct way below.

```
static transpose(matrix) {
let result = new Matrix(matrix.cols, matrix.rows);
for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
    result.data[j][i] = matrix.data[i][j];
  }
}
return result;
```

}

One thing I still want to ask from js community is that why the heck, is js so bad in giving errors. I've coded in java for quite a lot, and I know that it would have immediatelly shown the error REAL TIME when coding and saving a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

> original answer in quotes

> It looks like the `Matrix` class stores its data in a property called `matrix`, not `data`. Here's the timestamp showing where the `Matrix` class is defined https://youtu.be/puWqNBFDMMk?t=170

Updated to take into account `matrix` renamed to `data`:

```js
class Matrix {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.data = [];

    // ..(snip)..
  }
}
```

> Changing `result.data` to `result.matrix` should fix the `cannot set properties of undefined` error you're seeing.

However, you're going to immediately run into another error, which is that `static` methods cannot access `this`, since they're called on the class itself, as opposed to an instance of the class. You should change `this` to `matrix`, referring to the matrix you pass as the argument. Here's the updated code:

```js
static transpose(matrix) {
  let result = new Matrix(matrix.cols, matrix.rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
      result.data[j][i] = matrix.data[i][j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You'll call the method like this:

```js
let m = new Matrix(2, 3);
Matrix.transpose(m);
```

Make sure that you've renamed `this.matrix` to `this.data` *and* `result.matrix` to `result.data`. He misses that in the video with the first find/replace and has to go back and fix it later, see the timestamp in my comment.

Comment: He changes the matrix class so it has the data property in the following video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuZbYEn8AvY&t=185s&ab_channel=TheCodingTrain.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer. Here's the timestamp for where the `transpose` method is updated https://youtu.be/HuZbYEn8AvY?t=610

Comment: In my original post I showed my code for transpose method, and I had already changed those to .data